# Como muestro los numeros pares e impares de un arreglo en C?

Tags: c

El programa consiste en un arreglo de 10 numeros, y pido un numero, si ese numero es par tango que mostrar todos los numeros pares del arreglo y su promedio, y si es impar, lo mismo, como puedo hacerlo solo usando ?

Comment: Hola @Sarah Delgado, ya haz investigado algo?, ya tienes algún código?, que piensas que se necesita?

Comment: Ya he investigado y solo he encontrado como mostrar los pares e impares en otros dos arreglos, y necesito que se muestre dependiendo del numero

Comment: `#include<stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
int N[100]; 
int i,j,a,x; 
//Capturando los valores del arreglo  
for (i=0; i <10; i=i+1) 
{ 
  printf("Escribe un numero :", i+1); 
  scanf("%d",&N[i]); 
}`

Comment: //Pedir un valor
printf("\nTecle un numero: ");
scanf("%d", &x);

//Comparar si es par o inpar
if( x % 2 == 0){
    if(N[i] % 2==0)
       printf("%d", N[i]);
       N[i]++;
}else{
        printf("%d", N[i]);
        N[i]++;
    }
 
}

Comment: el usuario debe teclear un valor.  Si es par, muestra todos los elementos pares y el promedio de ellos; si es non, muestra todos los elementos impares y su promedio.

Comment: Genial ahora tienes que recorrer el arreglo que recibiste para validarlo no? for(unsigned int a = 0; a < sizeof(N); a = a + 1 ){ //CODIGO DE VALIDACION PAR / IMPAR } Disculpa habia puesto una funcion no valida en C

Comment: foreach dentro de que libreria esta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para determinar si un número es par, debe comprobar si al trazar su módulo con respecto a 2, este resulta nulo. Es decir, todo número par verifica en C:

```
int numero;

if (numero % 2 == 0) //Par...
```

En cualquier otro caso, con cualquier otro resto diferente de cero, el número es impar. Si no está usted familiarizada con este tipo de operación, le recomendaría un estudio cuanto menos superficial de aritmética modular. Es una herramienta muy útil en problemas de lo más diverso, muy alejados de las matemáticas puras.

Continuando con su pregunta, en caso de que su vector no esté ordenado de ninguna forma ni guarde una distribución en concreto, no se me ocurre más solución que comprobar la paridad de cada elemento para cerciorarla. Simplemente recorrería el vector y seleccionaría aquellos con igual paridad que el número inicial.

Comment: se te agradece el apoyo, pero en SO en español se pide que el OP muestre el mínimo intento o lo que ha investigado, para que partiendo de ahí se le apoye y comprenda mejor como resolver su problema; no únicamente dándole el código

Comment: No le comprendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @BorjaGonzálezSeoane sabia que se usa if (numero % 2 == 0) para buscar el numero par, solo que no sabia como imprimirlo si el numero que me daba era par o inpar, pero creo que lo he entendido al final de su comentario

Comment: @RubenHernandez muchas gracias por tu apoyo y por querer ayudarme a mejorar mi conocimiento conforme a lo que tengo

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con lo que me comentan. Lo tendré más en cuenta. Saludos.

Comment: Mi compilador esta fallando, pero esto es lo que hice...
`if( x % 2 == 0){ 
  for(i=0; i=x;i++)
  printf("%d",N[i]);
  }else if( x % 2 >= 0){ 
    for(i=0; i=x;i++)
    printf("%d",N[i]);
  }`

Comment: Esto deberia funcionarte for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
    if(x%2==0){
        for(int i=0;i=x;i++) printf("%d",N[i]);
    }else if( x % 2 >= 0){
        for(int i=0;i=x;i++) printf("%d",N[i]); 
    }
} Observa el INT en los for y agregue el ciclo principal para recorrer x

Comment: @SarahDelgado tú dices: *Mi compilador esta fallando*, y eso es incorrecto, el compilador te esta señalando un error. Si tu compilar fallaria de verdad mejor no lo uses :-).

Comment: ok @RubenHernandez lo voy a verificar, gracias :)

Comment: @eyllanesc voy a empezar a usar el compilador de code blocks, porque estoy haciendo otras 12 practicas en ese compilador y no quieren correr programas que ya corrian, pero muchas gracias

Comment: @SarahDelgado si es asi es quizas por la version del compilador, los compiladores más antiguos dejaban pasar los errores(y eso es mucho peor ya que podemos pensar que el programa es estable pero en realidad no lo es), y los actuales ya lo pueden detectar. Por otro lado cuando el compilador ve que hay un error el te lanza un mensaje, y eso mensaje es una de las cosas más importantes aparte del código para resolver el problema asi que para las siguientes ocasiones es recomendable que muestres el mensaje de error y el código como edición de tu pregunta, la sección comentario no es util para ello.

Comment: ok muchas gracias @eyllanesc de hecho los errores que me muestra mi compilador la mayoria de las veces son mi coco, lo tomare en cuenta para mis preguntas

Comment: @SarahDelgado probablemente no lo entiendas porque no sabes que significa ese mensaje, es decir la causa y por ende no sabes como resolverlo, pero aprovechando tus futuras preguntas los miembros de la comunidad te podrian enseñar a interpretarlas y corregirlas, y asi podrias solucionar tus futuros problemas. :)

Comment: @RubenHernandez sigue sin funcionar con la ayuda qu me diste, cuando meto el numero en el programa(ejemplo: 2) me imprime muchisimas veces el 2

Comment: Si y es porque en el for siempre llega al numero que selecciona el usuario, aquí echale cabeza **int i=0;i=x;i++**, SI por ejemplo selecciono 2 el recorrido del for seria 0, 1, 2

Comment: Segun yo falta un = para que se compare y no le de el valor de x

Comment: Mas bien es la logica que esta siguiendo ese for no cuadra con lo que tu quieres, solo estas recorriendo de nuevo el arreglo sin validarlo,  Lo que planteas. "Tengo una lista de 10 numeros, de los cuales si el usuario elige uno par muestro todos los pares" tu código esta diciendo "Tengo una lista de diez números, el usuario elige uno valido que sea par o impar y le muestro ese numero varias veces mas"